# Ubuntu 22.04 + network Ricoh IM C2000 printer

Tags: networking, printing, ricoh

I've recently installed the Ubuntu 22.04 OS on my laptop and now I'm not able to use my studio printer (Ricoh IM C2000 on the local network) anymore (I was able to use it with Ubuntu 18).

What should I check?
Do I have to install additional drivers?
Thank you so much for your support

**Edit 2022/09/26**

I've tried to use the commands suggested by @brian_p

```
I've used lpadmin -p C2000 -v "ipp://10.3.3.20" -E -m everywhere
```

Now I see a new printer added to my printers and I tried to print with it.
Nothing happens, I keep getting the same behavior I had trying to manually add the printer using the GUI tools.

I keep seeing the print queue that contains my document that was just sent for printing remaining pending and the printer idle (after a while the printer pauses).

[a screenshot of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFWeq.png)

Comment: Yes, you may need to install the same you installed before.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful comment

Comment: You were running Ubuntu Core 18 before?

Comment: I was running the Ubuntu Studio 18.04.
Honestly I don't remember if I installed something to be able to print with it

Comment: I think Ricoh do provide drivers - have a look at their downloads page: http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/rc3/model/imc2000/imc2000.htm

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem they have driver for Linux Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Execute `driverless`. This gives you a **URI**. Substitute in `lpadmin -p C2000 -v "URI" -E -m everywhere` and print to C2000.

Comment: Thank you @brian_p for you answer.
Let's suppose my printer has a static IP 10.3.3.20.
So, I should first use the `driveless http://10.3.3.20` command. Is it correct?

When I try the command i get the following result:
`ERROR: Unable to create PPD file: Could not poll sufficient capability info from the printer (http://10.3.3.20, http://10.3.3.20) via IPP!`

Comment: @orestino The command to use is `driverless`, nothing more and nothing less. See the manual: `man driverless`.